# Impossible to make IP static - SOLVED

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp

I may be had an upgrade problem from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 that I can't solve.
My IP was before static at 192.168.0.100 on the "ens1" interface, but the interface have been set to "enp3s0" during the upgrade. The "ifconfig" command result:

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
...
```

In the /etc/network/interfaces , my previous settings have also been turn to ignored:

```
# allow-hotplug ens1
# iface ens1 inet static
# address 192.168.0.100 
# netmask 255.255.255.0
# gateway 192.168.0.254
```

If I update the settings with the new interface so:

```
allow-hotplug enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.254
```

I lose the network connection.

But what I can see on the XFCE4 applet is that the network manager seems have keep the "ens1" interface. So if I replace "enp3s0" with "ens1" in the interfaces's file like it was before, I can reach the network back, but I lose the network manager's icon, and my IP stay 192.168.0.11 ! What is this for a sorcery, and how can I set static my IP back ?

Comment: The `/etc/network/interfaces` mechanism is no longer used. I suggest that you set the static details in Network Manager.

Comment: The Network Manager's icon was not always present in the Xfce4'panel, so I used nmtui to set my IP static and delete the old "ens1" connexion out of date. Better startup now, and Network Manager's icon is back :)

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please don't edit the question to add "solved". Post an answer describing the solution, and mark it as accepted instead.